# unable comparing data in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I wanna compare arraylist with my status list to display unBlocked status in main fragment, this is data that I want to compare

```
this is **idStatusBlocked = {"sdads # asdadsf # advdvff"};**<br>
this is **listData = [{"idStatus":"asdfsdf", "name":"BWaaa"}, {"idStatus":"advdvff","name":"aaaa"}];**
```

this code is before I impementing blocked action

```
@Override
public void setList(List<StatusObject> listData){
    adapter.addAll(listData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and for implementing blocked action, this is what I try

```
@Override
public void setList(List<StatusObject> listData){

    PreferenceHelper helper = new PreferenceHelper(mContext);
    String item = helper.getString(PreferenceHelper.BLOCK);
    String[] idStatusBlocked = item.split("#");

    List<StatusObject> filter = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String v : idStatusBlocked) {
        if (!listData.contains(v)) {
            filter.add((StatusObject) listData);
        }       
    }
}
```

what i got from code above is only comparing size of **listData** with **idStatusBlocked** and what i want is
**1.** How can I compare `idStatus` in `listData` with `idStatusBlocked` ?
**2.** After comparing the data, how can I dispay it with my adapter?

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes, its from my code, but i rewrite it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `setList` to this

```java
@Override
public void setList(List<StatusObject> listData){
    PreferenceHelper helper = new PreferenceHelper(mContext);
    String item = helper.getString(PreferenceHelper.BLOCK);

    Set<String> blocked = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(item.split("#")));
    List<StatusObject> filter = new ArrayList<>();

    for (StatusObject s : listData) {
        if (!blocked.contains(s.getIdStatus())) {
            filter.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```